# Flex Air LocalHost Error?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to compile an air app, and I keep getting this error:

D:\Tomcat\webapps\public-html\adm\Main.swf (The device is not ready)

It seems that someone who worked before me, had worked from a local server.

I searched Flex for all known variations, I couldn't find where it is looking for this.

I googled as well, which didn't get me anywhere.
Does anyone know how to remove this compiling error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to that drive/path?

Comment: How are you trying to compile the AIR app?  Are you using an ANT Script?  Or a Flash Builder project?  Or are you running something on the command line?  If the cmmand line, or an ANT Script, share the relevant bits.  If you're using Flash Builder, then provide more details about the project.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses. The drive path is actually my DVD drive. From what it seems, the previous developer was using it as localhost. I am using FlashBuilder4, simply clean/rebuilding using Project->Clean.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Flash Builder, it sound like you imported a project that had directories pointed at alternate locations.

I suggest that you bring up your project properties and check the bin-debug folder's location:

1) From the project menu, select Properties

2) Select Flex Build Path

3) Look at the "Output Folder" value.  Is it that D Drive location?  If so, change it to something on your local machine which you have write access to.  If not...

4) Click the Source Path tab in the Flex Build Path window

5) Are there any folders listed that are invalid for your local setup?  If so, change these to directories you have access to.  This will be trickier than the previous because any of these directories may contain source code you need to successfully compile.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Original Poster.

I had forgotten that I posted this question on a guest account, and now I don't know if I can go back in and mark it as the correct answer. I did upvote it however.

I am still a bit new here, and if I can go back to mark it as correct, I will. Sorry.
Once again, Flextras.com's solution was the answer for me.

Note: When going through Flextra.com's answer, make sure that you are on the properties for the correct project/folder. Originally, I was stuck wondering where it was, until I realized I was simply on the wrong main.mxml, which brought me to the wrong properties tab.

Thank you!